# Bigcommerce Cart Contents xfer to Another

Tags: cookies, e-commerce, cart, bigcommerce, tld

We want to operate two separate bigcommerce sites across tld (.ca & .com). The sites will be virtually identical aside from currency.

To make it user friendly, I want to have the cart contents transfer over, so if a user starts a cart in .com and realizes they need to switch to .ca it is persistent when they do.

I imagine the contents of the cart are stored in the user cookies somewhere and I can just develop some code to fill the cart using a cross reference for the .ca/.com site.

Does anyone know where the cart contents are stored in the cookies?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that the browser stores the cookies for different domains in separate areas, so you can't access them cross-site. You could log their IP and attach it to the cart instead, though I'm not proficient enough to know the details of how to do it.